# Apply code for all else first block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this code for sidebar in Wordpress :-

```
 register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Main sidebar',
'description' => 'main sidebar.',
'before_widget' => '<div id="blocks" class="siderbar box_outer %2$s" style="visibility: hidden;"><div class="widget">',
'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget_title">',
'after_title' => '</h3><div class="wid_border"></div>'
  ));
```

In this cod will add every widget attribute `style="visibility: hidden;"`, but i need to add this attribute for all widget else first widget.

How can do that by php or JQuery.

Comment: could you show the outputtet HTML

Comment: `$('.widget').not(':first')` could be the jQuery selector you need

Comment: @Mazzekazze can you edit in my code i try but not work

Comment: What can i do @Mazzekazze